# Can I autoplay sounds using Surveymonkey?

Tags: surveymonkey

As the title says, is it possible to enable autoplay for embedded videos in Surveymonkey? I have tried to embed a YouTube video with autoplay allowed but it doesn't look like this functionality is supported?

Answer (score 0):

Better you use Examinare instead. Use the Comment to add youtube clip in there with autoplay. The design is also better than they monkey script.

https://surveytools.examinare.com/